# Rust: Why passing unused (_) parameter to function changes the outcome

Tags: rust

Why below snippet errors out

```
fn print() -> &str
{
   let name2 = "blah";
   return &name2;
}

fn main() {
   let x = print();
   println!("{}", x);
}
```

but not this

```
fn print(_: &str) -> &str
{
   let name2 = "blah";
   return &name2;
}

fn main() 
{
   let x = print("");
   println!("{}", x);
}
```

The only difference is the additional parameter which is ignored in the last case

Comment: You've declared a local variable let name2 = "blah"; that will disappear at the end of the scope of your function. To continue using a reference to it, you need to specify his lifetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message tells you quite clearly why the first snippet fails:

> ```
> 1 | fn print() -> &str
>   |               ^ expected named lifetime parameter
> ```

you're returning a *reference*, references must have a lifetime to indicate their validity. You don't provide a lifetime and rustc's rules don't provide any either, so the compilation fails.

In the second snippet, you pass in a reference. Following [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html):

> If there is exactly one input lifetime position (elided or not), that lifetime is assigned to all elided output lifetimes.

rustc will use the input lifetime for the output, hence the second snippet is in essence

```
fn print(_: &'a str) -> &'a str
```

Since a string literal has lifetime `'static`, it can be "cast down" to any lifetime (since they're all shorter), therefore returning `name2` which is an `&'static str` does not break the contract: it will be valid for whatever the caller provides and wants.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the declaration is missing the lifetime specifier.
You could fix this declaration with the lifetime you use:

```
fn print() -> &'static str {
   let name2 = "blah";
   return &name2;
}
```

In the second one, you're using implicit lifetimes (with Rust Edition 2018).

Implicit lifetimes really means the lifetime of the function parameter is the lifetime on output. It is thus specified.

What you're implicitly declaring is this:

```
fn print<'a>(_: &'a str) -> &'a str {
   let name2 = "blah";
   return &name2;
}
```

It "works" but only because both the argument given and the implementations are based on static lifetime. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to call it. It thus adds really nothing over the first fixed version.

[more on implicit anonymous lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/ownership-and-lifetimes/the-anonymous-lifetime.html)